# how to open access database with password in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2007, connection-string

how can I open an MS Access 2007 database with a password in c# ?

I have tried this: `Conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\BioDB.mdb ;Password=1966;");`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What exact error message are you receiving?  There are many possible reasons why you couldn't open that database.

Comment: As a side note, one of my personal favorites is the complete lack of a provider for x64.  I *really* don't like access.

Comment: You can use Access 2010 beta for x64, drivers available now for download.

Comment: Why would there be a 64-bit Jet/ACE when there's no released 64-bit Access? If 64-bit is required, why have you chosen a data store that doesn't have 64-bit support? Looks like pilot error to me, not some lack in the database engine or its support by MS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

From:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/access

And as noted below use `@`.

Comment: how about username?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=BioDB.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1966;"`

Comment: how about username?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to escape that backslash, or precede the string with `@`.

Comment: Er, what backslash needs to be escaped? And in what context?

Comment: The only backslash in the original post; in the context of a C# string.

Comment: OK. C# programmers would understand that, but I think it would be better to be more explicit in an answer in specifying exactly what you're addressing.

Comment: The OP stated they are using C# and the question is tagged C#. I think it is a bit redundant to keep stating the language.

Comment: I think you're assuming too much about your readers and about the context in which your answer may be read.

Answer (score 0):

This is the connection string to use when you have an Access 2007 - 2013 database protected with a password using the "Set Database Password" function in Access.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

Some reports of problems with password longer than 14 characters. Also that some characters might cause trouble. If you are having problems, try change password to a short one with normal characters.